# Вывести дату меньше текущей на пол года

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Помогите написать запрос. Необходимо вывести из таблицы с датами (dd.mm.yyyy), только те, которые меньше на 6 месяцев от текущей.

Comment: Какая СУБД ? Что не получается сейчас, кажется, что запрос элементарный. Приложите, пожалуйста, свои попытки решения

Comment: phpmyadmin, я в принципе не понимаю как написать,что бы конкретно от текущей даты отсчитывало

Comment: phpmyadmin это интерфейс. На сервере у вас конкретная БД, предполагаю, что MySql

Comment: да, использую mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table test(dt date);
insert into test values('01.01.2018');
insert into test values('01.07.2018');

select * 
  FROM test t 
 where t.DT <= ADDDATE(current_date(), -180)
```

где `current_date()` возвращает текущую дату, а `ADDDATE(current_date(), -180)` вычитает из текущей даты, что примерно равно 6 месяцам.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01f63/2/0

Comment: 180 дней != 6 месяцев  https://habr.com/post/146109/

Comment: `WHERE t.DT <= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)`

Comment: @kot-da-vinci я ведь по этому и написал "примерно равно" =)